# view html code of cordova app when running on ios simulator

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

I have a strange bug where my app looks different in ios safari browser and as native build (cordova) on my iDevice and iOS Simulator. Is it possible to view the rendered html code with xcode dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use XCode to publish to an iDevice
2. open Safari
3. locate your iDevice under the "Develop" Tab
4. select the "index.html" page option

From there you can get the standard Developer tool for Safari and go nuts testing.